# Create Azure Cloud Service Package VSO Build with NuGet Package Restore

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I have an Azure cloud service that contains a web role. I have a CI build running in Visual Studio Online which uses TfvcTemplate.12.xaml build template. The projects in the solution reference NuGet packages which are restored using Automatic Package Restore (ref. http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore).

When I build the solution using the build template on the CI server everything builds fine.

When I build the Azure Cloud Service using the build template on the CI server the NuGet packages fail to restore. The idea is to build the cloud service and create a package.

This fails...

[image]

Is this the correct way to try to build a cloud service to create the package? I'd like to run package commands as MS Build parameters.

Thanks

Comment: You want to package your cloud service as a NuGet package?

Comment: Also, the template in your screenshot is the continuous deployment template.